# WinCE ARM input virtual keyboard

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce, inputstream, keyboard-events

I want to show virtual keyboard when i click on textbox. Any ideas how to implement virtual keyboard to my app? 
This code does nothing at all.

```
    private void textBox1_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        inputPanel1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void textBox1_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        inputPanel1.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: `Enabled` only toggles if the control responds to events. Maybe you want `Visible` property?

Comment: Are those actual event handlers attached to events, or did you just [paste the code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsce.forms.inputpanel.aspx)?

Comment: I just paste the code, but now i attached those to events but it only shows for one second and than close

Comment: @franzp Try removing the `LostFocus` handler.

Comment: Removing LostFocus handler worked. but it shuld have worked also with LostFocus... strange

Comment: @franzp Enabling the keyboard probably takes the focus off the textbox for a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LostFocus handler removing helped.

than i had to change position of keyboard. This is the only way to do it cuz of non existing property ://.. Maybe it will be useful for someone.

```
    [DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool SipGetInfo(
        ref SIPINFO sipInfo);

    [DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool SipSetInfo(
        ref SIPINFO sipInfo);
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]

    public struct SIPINFO
    {
        public uint cbSize;
        public uint fdwFlags;
        public RECT rcVisibleDesktop;
        public RECT rcSipRect;
        public uint dwImDataSize;
        public IntPtr pvImData;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public int left;
        public int top;
        public int right;
        public int bottom;
    }

    private void ShowInputPanel(Control control)
    {
        InputPanel.SIPINFO sipInfo;
        var x = 100;
        var y = control.PointToScreen(new Point(110, 150)).Y;            //control.Height

        this.inputPanel1.Enabled = true;

        sipInfo = new InputPanel.SIPINFO();
        sipInfo.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(sipInfo);
        if (InputPanel.SipGetInfo(ref sipInfo))
        {
            sipInfo.rcSipRect.left = x;
            sipInfo.rcSipRect.top = y;

            InputPanel.SipSetInfo(ref sipInfo);
        }
    }

    private void textBox1_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ShowInputPanel(this.textBox1);        
    }
```